# Do we have cross-language vector space for word embedding?

Tags: natural-language-processing, word-embedding

Do we have cross-language vector space for word embedding?

When measure similarity for apple/Pomme/mela/Lacus/苹果/りんご, they should be the same

If would be great if there's available internet service of neuron network which already be trained by multiple language

Answer (score 2):

You can try to read about MUSE (Multilingual Unsupervised and Supervised Embeddings) by Facebook. You can read it [from its Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE) or [this article](https://code.fb.com/ml-applications/under-the-hood-multilingual-embeddings/). They also provide the FastText dictionary format (.vec file) for some languages.

Their [original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04087.pdf) shows how it aligns the vector of words from two different languages:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For cross-language word representation the trend now is:

- **ELMoForManyLangs**: [git_repo](https://github.com/HIT-SCIR/ELMoForManyLangs) [original_paper_March_2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05365.pdf)
- **MUSE by Facebook**: [git_repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/MUSE) [original_paper_January_2018](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04087.pdf)

Remember that you can also do the task in 2 steps: 
**Translate** the words to a reference language (e.g english), then **represent** each one of them using any word representation model (in the reference language).

The 2-steps option is also good as specific-language word representation models are more accurate, and there are a bench of easy-to-use libraries for single-language translation (*i.e [py-translator](https://pypi.org/project/py-translator/)*) and representation (*i.e [Universal sentence encoder by Google](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2)*).